# Strongly Type Method Name

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to get a methods name and add it to a list. I had a look around and came across actions. So far I have the following:

```
    Protected Function MethodToString(method As Action) As String

        Return method.Method.Name

    End Function

 ...

    Me.Stages.Add(MethodToString(GetWeightFromSID()))
```

but it does not work when called as it says expression do not produce a value. I am pretty much just looking for the methods name. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action is a delegate, so you need to pass the [address of the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx), not call the method:

```
Me.Stages.Add(MethodToString(AddressOf GetWeightFromSID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflect.getmethods.aspx), for example to get all method-names of the current class as `List(of String)`:

```
' get names of all properties and methods in the current class '
Dim methodNames = (From info In Me.GetType.GetMethods Select info.Name).ToList
```